# Android studio: How to connect to existing VPN from android settings

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service

I am beginner in android and developing an app where I want to connect to an existing VPN connection (already configured in the android settings) during startup.

So far, I was able to open the settings activity via intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_VPN_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I don't want to click every time I open the app manually to connect.

Is there a way to click programmatically? I think there should be a way, because the app "Automagic Premium" goes exactly that way, but I don't know how.

I found for example:

```
View.performClick()
```

but how to get the view of the currently started intent?

Or is there another way to connect?

I tested also the VpnService class, but here it seems that there is only the possibility to create new profiles and using your own service implementation. That's not really what I am looking for.

I read lot of posts but found no satisfactory solution. Hope one of you can help me out? I am happy with every kind of hint.
Thanks

Comment: Just start it from onCreate or some other lifecycle method

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really help. I start the settings activity from the onCreate of my MainActivity. But how to proceed?